# mysql_query() returns syntax error

Tags: mysql

Just a small problem I'm having with an SQL query. It returns a syntax error, and after searching for quite some time, I can't find the problem. Can any of you find it?

Query:

```
INSERT INTO `blogposts` (id,'author','subject','content',date) VALUES (2,$author,$subject,$content,$date)
```

The variables `$author`,`$subject`, and `$date` are recieved from a form. They are strings, `$date` is a date, and the number 2 is a number.

Comment: [Don't use mysql_* extension](http://www.php.net/en/mysql_query). Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: can you please post your error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote your input:

```
INSERT INTO `blogposts` (`id`,`author`,`subject`,`content`,`date`) VALUES (2,'$author','$subject','$content','$date')
```

Remember to escape them or use prepared statement. More importantly, stop using `mysql_query()` ! use MySQLi / PDO instead.

*sidenote:* `mysql_query()` will be deprecated at PHP version 5.5.0

Comment: post your resultant query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the fields by `:

```
INSERT INTO `blogposts` (`id`, `author`, `subject`, `content`, `date`) VALUES (2,'$author','$subject','$content,$date')
```

If your `ID` is autoincrementing, you should not set it, or put value = 0.
Make sure you escape the variables. Security reasons.

Try to move to PDO.